# Changing text color for dark mode in Flutter(with Dynamic Theme)?

Tags: flutter, colors, themes

Text turn to white when I got select dark mode but I want to make all texts white70 or something(including buttons and regular texts). How can I definde the default text color for dark mode?

My Theme data like this right now:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DynamicTheme(
        defaultBrightness: Brightness.light,
        data: (brightness) => ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      brightness: brightness,
        ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something similar to this (Feel free to change things as you'd like):

At first go to ios/Runner folder. Next open info.plist and add the following lines into the Dict section.

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

Next. Make sure you have these lines in Theme settings of your MaterialApp:

```
MaterialApp(
    themeMode: ThemeMode.light, // Change it as you want
    theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
        canvasColor: Colors.white,
        // next line is important!
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light)),
    darkTheme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColorLight: Colors.black,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColorDark: Colors.black,      
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        canvasColor: Colors.black,
        // next line is important!
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.dark)),
```