# How to change the Text color with change of theme in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing a App in flutter and it changes its theme data as per the theme of System i.e. if the user has enabled Dark mode for his device the app will automatically change to Dark mode and vice-versa.Here i want to change the text color of App too.

I have created **custom text Theme** as I don't want to change the default **TextThemeData**. The code of the same is as follows

**text_themes.dart**

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    extension CustomTextStyles on TextTheme {
    
      TextStyle get h1 {
        return TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        );
      }
       
      TextStyle get d1 {
        return TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Brightness.dark == null ? Colors.blue:Colors.white,
        );
      }
      TextStyle get d2 {
        return TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0);
      }
    }
```

The problem is that whenever i switch themes the text color doesn't change. I have tried using
`color: ThemeData.dark() == null ? Colors.blue[800] : Colors.white,`
and
`color: Brightness.dark() == null ? Colors.blue[800] : Colors.white,`
but nothing worked.

This is my expected output after above lines of code

[image: Expected]

This is my current output

[image: Actual]

**Main.dart**

```dart
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:kjssc/models/user_data.dart';
    import 'package:kjssc/screens/edit_profile_screen.dart';
    import 'package:kjssc/screens/home_screen.dart';
    import 'package:kjssc/screens/sign_up_screen.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'screens/login_screen.dart';
    import 'screens/sign_up_in_screen.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      static SharedPreferences mainSharedPreferences;
    
      Widget _getScreenID() {
        return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserID = snapshot.data.uid;
              return HomeScreen();
            } else {
              return SignUpInScreen();
            }
          },
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => UserData(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'My KJSSC',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: _getScreenID(),
            // theme: state.themeData,
            theme: ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
              primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white70,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            darkTheme: ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white54,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
    
            routes: {
              LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
              SignupScreen.id: (context) => SignupScreen(),
              EditProfileScreen.id: (context) => EditProfileScreen(),
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**homescreen.dart (Code snippet)**

```dart
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Text(
            'Email Id : ',
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.d1
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(
            'user1@gmail.com',
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.d2,
             overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
       ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing text color for dark mode in Flutter(with Dynamic Theme)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725659/changing-text-color-for-dark-mode-in-flutterwith-dynamic-theme)

Comment: @Taha20 no i have already created themes and custom theme data too. I want that to change to blue or different color for different theme mode

Comment: If you use `on ThemeData` instead of `TextTheme`, you'll be able to do `color: brightness == Brightness.dark ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,`

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Changing themes on Flutter should trigger a Widget rebuild. What I did on my approach was check the current theme and update the styles to be used on the Text widgets.

```
TextStyle? _textStyle;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
  bool isDarkMode = (brightness == Brightness.dark);
  
  /// Update TextStyle depending on the theme
  if (isDarkMode){
    _textStyle = CustomTextStyleDark();
  } else {
    _textStyle = CustomTextStyleDefault();
  }
  return ...
}
```